# Google Two-way factory authentication PHP

Tags: php, oauth

I want to have a Google Authenticator for my website (`PHP`) / 2FA.

**What I exactly want:**

- For the login page: username, password and (if enabled) GAuth (6 numbers).
- In profile settings a person can scan the QR code in his Google Authenticator app and enable/disable the GAuth.
- I do NOT want to use the google login button, just the 6 number authentication.

*Info: It's a game website where people can register their account, which means every QR code is personalized to one user.*

**Question:**

- I have been searching the web a lot on how to implement this AND how to generate a QR code, but I have not found a useful tutorial. How can I implement this API?

I've installed composer `https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client`, but now I'm stuck.

Comment: You're searching for the wrong thing. This has nothing to do with OAuth. It's called two-factor authentication. [Lots of tutorials and libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+two+factor+authentication) for that.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz, Do you have a link with tutorial? It should be free, joomla is using one as well. I cannot find one.

Comment: I linked to a Google search that finds many libraries and tutorials.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz now I understand what to do, atleast I know where to continue. Feel free to add an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the app is Google's, what you are looking for is not an API from google. What you need is a TOTP php class.
Here is one (quite old) that you can use: https://www.idontplaydarts.com/static/ga.php_.txt